# How to add different colours to front and back of shape with material side double in a-frame

Tags: aframe

Working with a-frame - Lets say I have a 2d shape such as a triangle or plane. If I set the material to side: double - is it possible to have different colours/materials on the 2 sides?
Here is an example of what I'm working with

```
 <a-triangle 
            vertex-a="11.25 0 -18.75"
            vertex-b="15 0 -20"
            vertex-c="10 0 -20" 
            color="red"
            material="side: double"
            shadow>
          </a-triangle>
```

And I would like for example, for the triangle to have a red front and a black back.

Is this currently possible? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material side double is to make a geometry visible on both sides. You can simulate a single plane or triangle with two different sides with two planes or triangles oriented in oposite directions and different colors.